# Would it be impermissible for me to get married?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

I suffer from mental trauma which I suspect would cause difficulty with
intimacy in a prospective marriage (I have not been married previously).
I've tried professional help, but I do not think this has helped. 
I'm secure in other aspects of life (financially, physically etc) but can't seem to resolve this problem within myself.
Given my circumstance, would it be impermissible for me to proceed with the marriage, seeing as there is a chance I might not be able to fulfill one of my duties as a spouse?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your future spouse aware of your medical problem ?

Comment: @ZakC Yes, she is.

Answer (score 1):

I asked for the awareness of the spouse, the answer is positive.

These sort of questions are technically hard. Asking if something is forbidden is simple: a positive answer comes with sources, texts, reasons.

Asking if something is permissible is harder: a positive answer is the *absence* of sources, texts, and reasons.

So from my many readings, I am unaware of a single source that would make this marriage unlawful. Nor am I aware of a single source that says tetraplegiacs or extremely old people should not get married (in fact, one of the companions of the Prophet, Muadh, was married on his deathbed because he did not want to die celibate).

If there is no dishonesty between the spouses regarding the various conditions, then there is nothing stopping you.

What I *have* read is that it could be discouraged if you had no sexual desire (if you are asexual or homosexual, for instance, whereby the spouse is *used* only to conform to a social norm, and not because of a desire for her, which basically amounts to stealing her life and trapping her in a loveless marriage).

But **having** a sexual desire that you have difficulty fulfilling, while regrettable, does not make the marriage unlawful. Good luck to you both.

Answer (score -2):

Why not? Islam is a open religion - it clearly mentions what is prohibited and anything outside these realms is not prohibited. As long as both yourself and your future spouse are aware of any underlying conditions and are prepared to work together to overcome issues together, I personally see no problem.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to this video link, InshaAllah this will helps
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4AA58V9PV_o

Comment: Please summarize the answer within your post, as otherwise it will become useless if the video is removed in the future.